# SDL2: Is there a way to just extend the default Menu function already implemented in SDL2

Tags: macos, menu, sdl-2

Rather than starting from scratch and implementing a new menu treatment, Is there a simple way to just extend the existing menu bar provided in SDL2. On MacOS X I see "Apple, AppName, and Window" already implemented and serviced by SDL2. I'd like to add menu items and content without having to start over.

I've searched the net for a solution without success. Perhaps this is too simple a question?